# Micro USB to USB adapter m/m

Tags: usb, arduino-micro

I'm looking into working with an Arduino micro, and I'd like to be able to plug it into my computer directly(without a cable). I've been looking around, and the best thing that I found was [this](http://www.gearbest.com/usb-flash-drives/pp_241630.html?currency=USD&gclid=Cj0KEQjwz-i3BRDtn53Z5Z7t4PUBEiQA23q2ADLBLxSTh67ggFcvjZenuXTcFK6nriQfRnaFchLybM8aAuhx8P8HAQ). The reason I haven't bought the linked adapter is because I've seen a number of bad reviews of the seller with close to half of the reviews being 1-star. Anybody have an idea where I can find something similar?

EDIT: I'm going to be using this for security testing, emulating a rubber ducky usb, so I need the computer to recognize the Arduino as an HID, not an arduino, but I also (obviously) need to be able to load my code onto it

Comment: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/2Pcs-Micro-USB-Male-to-USB-Female-OTG-Adapter-Converter-For-Android-Tablet-Phone-/281886855395?hash=item41a1c410e3:g:-7IAAOSwwE5WXp6V . But it's the wrong one like Majenko said

Comment: Hack a usb male onto the board and plug it in.

Comment: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/USB-male-type-A-to-micro-USB-male-adapter-converter-for-cellphone-camera-mp3-4-/231488735028?hash=item35e5cdc734:g:Qk8AAOSwbqpTwPNc This is the smallest I could find at the moment.

Comment: @J. Doe, This isn't really the place for shopping recommendations. Questions on Arduino, code, usage, etc are fine. I also don't see how an adapter would be way better as a cable. And Gerben has a sufficient answer (in my opinion). So I'm voting to close this question since it's more about USB connectors as actually about Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

That adapter is not suitable. Not only is it the wrong gender on the large end, but it is designed for a completely different purpose.

That is an "On The Go" adapter which is designed for connecting things with a USB A plug (such as a memory stick, etc) to a mobile phone's USB socket.  It is not suitable for connecting things to an Arduino.

I have never heard of an adapter like you want, but I have heard of Arduino-like boards that plug direct into a computer like you want. One example is the [Digispark from Digistump](http://digistump.com/products/1) which is an ATTiny85 on a USB plug.

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify what I'll be using it for to see if it makes a difference.